# psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation * already exists while populatig a database via MRjob

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, hadoop, mrjob

I'm trying to populate a postgresql database by using MRjob. Some days ago someone kindly suggested me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34758338/how-to-populate-a-postgresql-database-with-mrjob-and-hadoop/35122640#35122640) to divide in steps the mapper. I tried but an error is given:

```
python db_store_hadoop.py -r local --dbname=en_ws xSparse.txt
no configs found; falling back on auto-configuration
no configs found; falling back on auto-configuration
creating tmp directory /tmp/db_store_hadoop.iarroyof.20160204.074501.695246
writing wrapper script to /tmp/db_store_hadoop.iarroyof.20160204.074501.695246/setup-wrapper.sh

PLEASE NOTE: Starting in mrjob v0.5.0, protocols will be strict by default. It's recommended you run your job with --strict-protocols or set up mrjob.conf as described at https://pythonhosted.org/mrjob/whats-new.html#ready-for-strict-protocols

writing to /tmp/db_store_hadoop.iarroyof.20160204.074501.695246/step-0-mapper_part-00000
> sh -ex setup-wrapper.sh /usr/bin/python db_store_hadoop.py --step-num=0 --mapper --dbname en_ws /tmp/db_store_hadoop.iarroyof.20160204.074501.695246/input_part-00000 > /tmp/db_store_hadoop.iarroyof.20160204.074501.695246/step-0-mapper_part-00000
writing to /tmp/db_store_hadoop.iarroyof.20160204.074501.695246/step-0-mapper_part-00001
> sh -ex setup-wrapper.sh /usr/bin/python db_store_hadoop.py --step-num=0 --mapper --dbname en_ws /tmp/db_store_hadoop.iarroyof.20160204.074501.695246/input_part-00001 > /tmp/db_store_hadoop.iarroyof.20160204.074501.695246/step-0-mapper_part-00001
STDERR: + __mrjob_PWD=/tmp/db_store_hadoop.iarroyof.20160204.074501.695246/job_local_dir/0/mapper/0
STDERR: + exec
STDERR: + /usr/bin/python -c import fcntl; fcntl.flock(9, fcntl.LOCK_EX)
STDERR: + export PYTHONPATH=/tmp/db_store_hadoop.iarroyof.20160204.074501.695246/job_local_dir/0/mapper/0/mrjob.tar.gz:/home/iarroyof/shogun-install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/home/iarroyof/shogun/examples/undocumented/python_modular:/home/iarroyof/smo-mkl/python:
STDERR: + exec
STDERR: + cd /tmp/db_store_hadoop.iarroyof.20160204.074501.695246/job_local_dir/0/mapper/0
STDERR: + /usr/bin/python db_store_hadoop.py --step-num=0 --mapper --dbname en_ws /tmp/db_store_hadoop.iarroyof.20160204.074501.695246/input_part-00000
STDERR: Traceback (most recent call last):
STDERR:   File "db_store_hadoop.py", line 86, in <module>
STDERR:     MRwordStore().run()
STDERR:   File "/tmp/db_store_hadoop.iarroyof.20160204.074501.695246/job_local_dir/0/mapper/0/mrjob.tar.gz/mrjob/job.py", line 461, in run
STDERR:     mr_job.execute()
STDERR:   File "/tmp/db_store_hadoop.iarroyof.20160204.074501.695246/job_local_dir/0/mapper/0/mrjob.tar.gz/mrjob/job.py", line 470, in execute
STDERR:     self.run_mapper(self.options.step_num)
STDERR:   File "/tmp/db_store_hadoop.iarroyof.20160204.074501.695246/job_local_dir/0/mapper/0/mrjob.tar.gz/mrjob/job.py", line 530, in run_mapper
STDERR:     for out_key, out_value in mapper_init() or ():
STDERR:   File "db_store_hadoop.py", line 35, in mapper_init
STDERR:     create_tables(self.cr0)
STDERR:   File "db_store_hadoop.py", line 14, in create_tables
STDERR:     cr.execute("create table word_list(id serial primary key, word character varying not null)")
STDERR: psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "word_list" already exists
STDERR: 
Counters from step 1:
  (no counters found)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "db_store_hadoop.py", line 86, in <module>
    MRwordStore().run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 461, in run
    mr_job.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 479, in execute
    super(MRJob, self).execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mrjob/launch.py", line 153, in execute
    self.run_job()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mrjob/launch.py", line 216, in run_job
    runner.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mrjob/runner.py", line 470, in run
    self._run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mrjob/sim.py", line 173, in _run
    self._invoke_step(step_num, 'mapper')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mrjob/sim.py", line 264, in _invoke_step
    self.per_step_runner_finish(step_num)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mrjob/local.py", line 152, in per_step_runner_finish
    self._wait_for_process(proc_dict, step_num)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mrjob/local.py", line 268, in _wait_for_process
    (proc_dict['args'], returncode, ''.join(tb_lines)))
Exception: Command ['sh', '-ex', 'setup-wrapper.sh', '/usr/bin/python', 'db_store_hadoop.py', '--step-num=0', '--mapper', '--dbname', 'en_ws', '/tmp/db_store_hadoop.iarroyof.20160204.074501.695246/input_part-00000'] returned non-zero exit status 1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "db_store_hadoop.py", line 86, in <module>
    MRwordStore().run()
  File "/tmp/db_store_hadoop.iarroyof.20160204.074501.695246/job_local_dir/0/mapper/0/mrjob.tar.gz/mrjob/job.py", line 461, in run
    mr_job.execute()
  File "/tmp/db_store_hadoop.iarroyof.20160204.074501.695246/job_local_dir/0/mapper/0/mrjob.tar.gz/mrjob/job.py", line 470, in execute
    self.run_mapper(self.options.step_num)
  File "/tmp/db_store_hadoop.iarroyof.20160204.074501.695246/job_local_dir/0/mapper/0/mrjob.tar.gz/mrjob/job.py", line 530, in run_mapper
    for out_key, out_value in mapper_init() or ():
  File "db_store_hadoop.py", line 35, in mapper_init
    create_tables(self.cr0)
  File "db_store_hadoop.py", line 14, in create_tables
    cr.execute("create table word_list(id serial primary key, word character varying not null)")
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "word_list" already exists
```

This is my job code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#Script for storing the sparse data into a database
import psycopg2
import re
import argparse
from mrjob.job import MRJob

def unicodize(segment):
    if re.match(r'\\u[0-9a-f]{4}', segment):
        return segment.decode('unicode-escape')
    return segment.decode('utf-8')

def create_tables(cr):
    cr.execute("create table word_list(id serial primary key, word character varying not null)")
    cr.execute("""create table word_sparse(
        id serial primary key, 
        word_id integer references word_list(id) not null,
        pos integer not null,
        val float not null)""")

def delete_tables(cr):
    cr.execute("drop table word_sparse")
    cr.execute("drop table word_list")

class MRwordStore(MRJob):
    #conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=%s user=semeval password=semeval" % args_n)
    def configure_options(self):
        super(MRwordStore, self).configure_options()
        self.add_file_option('--dbname')

    def mapper_init(self):
        # make sqlite3 database available to mapper
        self.conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname="+ self.options.dbname +" user=semeval password=semeval")
        self.cr0 = self.conn.cursor()
        create_tables(self.cr0)

    def mapper(self, _, line):
        self.cr = self.conn.cursor()
        item = line.strip().split('\t')
        replaced = u"".join((unicodize(seg) for seg in re.split(r'(\\u[0-9a-f]{4})', item[0])))
        key = u''.join((c for c in replaced if c != '"'))

        self.cr.execute("insert into word_list(word) values(%s) returning id", (key,))
        word_id = self.cr.fetchone()[0]

            #Parse the list, literal_eval is avoided because of memory issues
        inside = False
        number = ""
        pos = 0
        val = 0
        for c in item[1]:
            if c == '[':
                inside = True
            elif c.isdigit():
                number += c
            elif c == ',':
                if inside:
                    pos = int(number)
                    number = ""
            elif c == ']':
                if inside:
                    val = int(number)
                    number = ""
                    self.cr.execute("insert into word_sparse(word_id, pos, val) values (%s, %s, %s)", (word_id, pos, val))
                inside = False

    def mapper_final(self):

        self.conn.commit()
        self.conn.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    """
    Stores words in the database.

    The first time, run with the arguments -cs.
    If the database has to be recreated, run again with the d argument (-dcs)

    Use the -f argument to specify the input file (sparse data)
    Use the -n argument to specify the database name, which must be already created.

    It also asumes the owner of the database is a user named semeval with password semeval
    """

    MRwordStore().run()
```

If someone can help me identifying errors and misconceptions it would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of days trying I used an initial connection and `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ...` at the `__main__`. At the `mapper_init()` I created a new connection and cursor for each mapper. This is the script for populating a postgresql database via Hadoop:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Script for storing the sparse data into a database. 
# Dependencies: MRjob, psycopg2, postgresql and/or Hadoop.

import psycopg2
import re
import argparse
from mrjob.job import MRJob

dbname = "es_ws" 
# Following global was created for my custom application. You can avoid it.
dsm = True 

def unicodize(segment):
    if re.match(r'\\u[0-9a-f]{4}', segment):
        return segment.decode('unicode-escape')
    return segment.decode('utf-8')

def replaced(item):
    replaced = u"".join((unicodize(seg) for seg in re.split(r'(\\u[0-9a-f]{4})', item)))
    word = replaced.strip('"')
    return word

def insert_list_vector(cursor, word_id, vector):
   inside = False
   number = ""
   pos = 0
   val = 0
   for c in vector:
        if c == '[':
            inside = True
        elif c.isdigit():
                number += c
        elif c == ',':
            if inside:
                pos = int(number)
                number = ""
        elif c == ']':
            if inside:
                val = int(number)
                number = ""
                cursor.execute("insert into word_sparse(word_id, pos, val) values (%s, %s, %s)", (word_id, pos, val))
            inside = False

def insert_dict_vector(cursor, word, vector):
        palabra = word #replaced(palabra)
        d = vector #item[1] 
        bkey = True
        bvalue = False
        key = ""
        value = ""
        for c in d:
            if c == '{':
                pass
            elif c == ":":
                bkey = False
                bvalue = True
            elif c in (",","}"):
                bkey = True
                bvalue = False
                key = replaced(key.strip())
                value = int(value)
                sql = "INSERT INTO coocurrencias VALUES('%s', '%s', %s);"%(palabra, key, value)
                cursor.execute(sql)
                key = ""
                value = ""
            elif bkey:
                key += c
            elif bvalue:
                value += c

def create_tables(cr):
    if dsm:   
        cr.execute("create table if not exists coocurrencias(pal1 character varying, pal2 character varying, valor integer)")
        cr.execute("create table if not exists words(id integer, word character varying)") #(id integer, word character varying, freq integer)
    else:
        cr.execute("create table if not exists word_list(id serial primary key, word character varying not null)")
        cr.execute("""create table if not exists word_sparse(
                  id serial primary key, word_id integer references word_list(id) not null,
                  pos integer not null, val float not null)""")

class MRwordStore(MRJob):

    def mapper_init(self):
        self.conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname="+ dbname +" user=semeval password=semeval")

    def mapper(self, _, line):
        self.cr = self.conn.cursor()
        item = line.strip().split('\t')
        replaced = u"".join((unicodize(seg) for seg in re.split(r'(\\u[0-9a-f]{4})', item[0])))
        key = u''.join((c for c in replaced if c != '"'))     
    if dsm:
        self.cr.execute("insert into words(word) values(%s) returning id", (key,))
            word_id = self.cr.fetchone()[0]
            insert_dict_vector(cursor = self.cr, word = key, vector = item[1])
        else:          
            self.cr.execute("insert into word_list(word) values(%s) returning id", (key,))
            word_id = self.cr.fetchone()[0]
            insert_list_vector(cursor = self.cr, word_id = word_id, vector = item[1])

    def mapper_final(self):
        self.conn.commit()
        self.conn.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    """Stores word vectors into a database. Such a db (e.g. here is en_ws) must be previusly created in postgresql. 
    It also asumes the owner of the database is a user named semeval with password semeval.
    This script parses input_file.txt containing lines in the next example format (dsm=False):

    "word"<tab> [[number, number],[number, number], ...]

    or (dsm=True)

    "word"<tab> {key:value, key:value,...}

    Use example:

    python db_store_hadoop.py -r hadoop input_file.txt
    """
    # Firstly create tables once for avoiding duplicates.
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname="+ dbname +" user=semeval password=semeval")
    create_tables(conn.cursor()) # Overwrite this function for customing your tables
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()    

    # Run the MR object
    MRwordStore().run()
```

In the case someone has another suggestion it is welcome.